Spring boot does not load image


<img src="../assets/img/backgrounds/18.jpg" alt="img">

Spring boot not serving the assets content.
My HTML web pgae uploads image offline. But when I run the project, it does not upload image. My folder path, image name and extension are correct.

You can inspect the website to see what path the missing image is linked to, and from that you can get a clue where to put the image for it to appear.
Right click on the missing image and click on the Inspect. Then, at the upcoming window, you'll see the HTML and CSS in action.
For more info on this, here's an article: https://zapier.com/blog/inspect-element-tutorial/
EDIT:
If the following doesn't load:
<img src="file:///D:/ElizaDashboard/eliza-dashboard-develop/src/main/resources/assets/img/backgrounds/18.jpg" alt="img">

then this answer might help you.

I've inspected the image and confirmed that the link is correct. However, I suspect that the project is not properly serving the content of the other folder. To resolve this, I tried moving the image to the same folder as the HTML file, but it did not have any effect on the web page.

It still doesn't work out.

Would you like me to start a bounty in hope that someone might help you in this?
